# Discretization of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, discrete-geometry, discrete-calculus

I wish to find a specific discretization of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in such a way that the subsets obtained form hyperplanes of codimension 1. Let me explain:

If we consider a prime number $p$ then $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a product of cyclic groups of order $p^2$ and thus there are $p+1$ nontrivial proper subgroups, each one of them of order $p$, which are $$H_i=\{(k,l) \in \mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p : \; il\equiv k \; {\mbox{mod}}\; p\}, \: i=0, 1, ...,p-1, \quad\text{ and }\quad H_p=\{(k,0), \; k\in \mathbb{Z}_p\}.$$

Geometrically, they represent $(p+1)$ lines covering $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$  and all going through the origin.

Now my goal is to expand this to $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$. (Note that i haven't checked any of what i claim in what follows. This is rather an "intuitive guess"). Following the same reasoning, there are $p+1$ nontrivial proper subgroups of codimension $1$ each of them of order $p^{n-1}$, which are
$$H_i=\left\{z\in\mathbb{Z}^n_p\big| \exists l,k\in\{1,\dots , n\}:iz_l\equiv z_k\mod p\right\} \text{ for }i\in\{0,1,\dots,p-1\} \quad\text{ and }H_p=\left\{z\in\mathbb{Z}^n_p\big| \forall k\in\{1,\dots,n-1\}, z_k\in\mathbb{Z}_p\text{ and }z_n\equiv 0\mod p\right\}$$

As I said before this is just a guess (which is highly likely to be wrong) and I wish to do such a construction more precisely but I haven't find good sources for such topic.

Do you have any specific recommendations? Are my guesses correct?

Have a great day!

Comment: No, your guess is incorrect. There are $\frac{p^n-1}{p-1}$ subgroups of $\mathbb{F}_p^n$ of dimension $n-1$, and they are given by the $\{z \in \mathbb{F}_p^n,\, a_1z_1+\ldots+a_nz_n=0\}$, where $a $ runs through a set of representatives for $(\mathbb{F}_p^n\backslash \{0\} )/\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$.

Comment: Hey @Aphelli, thank you for your answer. Could you recommend some books where i could find more information on this topic?

Comment: I’m not sure (I don’t know what you exactly know) but maybe you could try textbooks on linear algebra.

Comment: For example, you use this notation of $\mathbb{F}^n_p$ and the result that you calim. I've never seen that. Where could i gain see exposition of this theory?

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_p$ is the number-theoretic notation for $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Then you just take the $n$-th Cartesian power.

Comment: This can be found in any book on abstract algebra. There $\Bbb F_p$ usually is a finite field with $p$ elements.